# path problem when i enter the streamlit run command in terminal

Tags: python, path, streamlit

```
streamlit : The term 'streamlit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ streamlit run c:/Users/Zbook 15 G5/OneDrive/Desktop/main.py/streamlit ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (streamlit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5>cd C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop>cd main.py

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop\main.py>cd streamlitenv

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop\main.py\streamlitenv>open main.py
'open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop\main.py\streamlitenv>streamlit run main.py
'streamlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop\main.py\streamlitenv>streamlit run main.py
'streamlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop\main.py\streamlitenv>streamlit run C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop\main.py
'streamlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Zbook 15 G5\OneDrive\Desktop\main.py\streamlitenv>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.